# How do I show the specific items in the navigated screen after on select gallery item in Powerapps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

Sample data:
[image]

Below is the vertical gallery image:

[image]

How it looks like after "Office" item in the vertical gallery is selected:
[image]

When on select office gallery item, I only want to show area description for storey 1, builingID 1 and area description to be Office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating a collection in the OnSelect property of the arrow icon on the first gallery. This can be achieved by using the following formula.

```
ClearCollect(
TempCollection,
Filter(
    Datasource,
    areaName = ThisItem.areaName
) )
```

You can then set TempCollection as the Items property for the second gallery